# atls.lib not in filesystem

Tags: visual-studio-2017, linker

There are similar questions on SO but they do not exactly anwer my problem: I have VS2017 Community Edition and atls.lib is missing in the filesystem.

Q1: My project compiles a plain C++ CLI-application, no MFC or the like. Why does it want to link to atls.lib?

Q2: I have read that one can add atls.lib to Linker->Input->Ignore_Specific_Default_Libraries but how would I do that via CMake where I do not have that dialog?

Answer (score 0):

[x] solved:

```
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} /NODEFAULTLIB:atls.lib")
```

did the job. And atls.lib can be installed via the Visual Studio installer. It's just a bit strange because the VS installer seems to belong to VS2019 but it works for VS2017 and VS2019.